# How to pass Mule expression to spring property

Tags: spring, mule

I'm looking for a way to assign an exception message to spring property at runtime in mule flow (Mule 3.3.0)

This is how my code-snippet looks like:

```
       <catch-exception-strategy>
            <logger message="----->Exception is #[exception.causeException]"
                level="INFO" />
            <custom-transformer
                class="com.company.transformer.VelocityMessageTransformer">
                <spring:property name="velocityEngine" ref="velocityEngine" />
                <spring:property name="templateName" value="soap11Fault.vm" />
                <spring:property name="beanClass">
                    <spring:bean parent="abstractSoap11ClientFault">
                        <spring:property name="faultString" value="Invalid Request" />
                        <spring:property name="detail" value="${exception.causeException}" />
                    </spring:bean>
                </spring:property>
            </custom-transformer>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
```

I want to assign exception cause to `detail` property here:

```
<spring:property name="detail" value="${exception.causeException}" />
```

but spring is looking for this property in properties file. I tried doing this also

```
 <spring:property name="detail" value="${#[exception.causeException]}" /> but doesn't work.
```

Is there a way to pass Mule expression at run-time to Spring property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties are set during the application initialization: the value you want to pass is evaluated at runtime, so that can't work.

What you need to do is make `com.company.transformer.VelocityMessageTransformer` extend `org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer`. You will then have to override `transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding)`, which will give you access to the current message and its associated exception payload. The exception payload is what you get with the `#[exception]` expression.

Comment: If you need to read a flowVar from a message transformer, you could use something like `String flowVar = message.getProperty("flowVarName", org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope.INVOCATION);`

Comment: Or better, use the generic form: `<T> T getInvocationProperty(String name)` http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.5.0/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleMessage.html#getInvocationProperty%28java.lang.String%29